# Treatment effect and Causal Structural Models (Pearl-type)

Tags: econometrics, nonparametric, causality, structural-equation-modeling

How can I check whether the condition of no confounding is satisfied in a Structural Causal Model? In particular is there a way to do this by applying the do-calculus?

The condition of no confounding is defined as

$$D \perp  (Y_1, Y_0) \lvert X \Leftrightarrow Pr(D\lvert  Y_1, Y_0 ,X) = Pr(D\lvert  X)$$

and the structural causal model I am considering is

\begin{align}
X &= \phi_X(U_X) \\[8pt]
D &= \phi_D(X,U_D) \\[8pt]
Y &= \phi_Y({D,X,U_Y}),
\end{align}
with the variable $Y_d(u):=Y_{M_d}$ an $Pr(U) = Pr(U_Y)Pr(U_X)Pr(U_D)$ and $U = (U_Y,U_X,U_D)$.

The variable $D$ is in this case the treatment variable taking only values $1$ or $0$.

Comment: If you have a causal diagram, please include that. On the face of it, I would say no, because $X$ is not a function of $D.$ $D$ in this scenario looks like a mediator, not a confounder.

Comment: The causal diagram including $(Y,D,X)$ is easy to read of from the structural model. But the question is concerning the variable $Y_d$ so I do not know how that should be included.

Comment: You can think of $Y_d$ as $Y$, but after having done graph surgery. Detach and replace the node $D$ by an input into $Y$. Your SCM would be \begin{align*}X&=\phi_X(U_x)\\Y_d&=\phi_Y(d,X,U_Y).\end{align*} Essentially, your causal diagram reduces down to $X\to Y_d.$

Comment: Agreed. But I do not see how that helps me answer the question?

Comment: Well, I don't know about using the do-calculus, but if there's only one edge in your causal graph, and the causal graph is accurate, then there can be no backdoor paths. If there are no backdoor paths, there is no confounding.

Comment: This is an untestable assumption. You can make a case for it holding in your setting using external information, but there isn't some algorithm you can apply.

Comment: Nonsense. The structural model is given, the question concerns model properties. Not whether these hold empirically. You are confusing things @Dimitry v. Masterov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structural model is implied by this graph.
[image]

The back-door criterion (e.g., Pearl 2009) states that $X$ fulfills it for the effect of $D$ on $Y$ if $X$ blocks all back-door paths form $D$ to $Y$, and if no element in $X$ is a descendant of $D$. Both conditions are true. So $X$ is sufficient for adjustment to identify the causal effect of $D$ on $Y$.

The back-door criterion furthermore implies $Y(d) \perp D|X$. This again is explained in the Pearl 2009, Causality, CUP.

One can also do it using the do-calculus, althoug this is really too complicated in this case. Generally,

$$P(Y|do(D)) = P(Y|do(D), x)P(x|do(D)).$$

Since $X$ does not affect $D$, rule 3 gives $P(x|do(D)) = P(x)$. Furthermore, Rule 2 applies and gives $P(Y|do(D), x) = P(Y|D, x)$. Accordingly, we have derived the adjustment formula

$$P(Y|do(D)) = P(Y|D, x)P(x)$$.